# Using xmlStar to get XML node attribute

Tags: command-line, xml, rss

I'm trying to get XML values from a rss feed XML using [xmlStar](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

`https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UC16niRr50-MSBwiO3YDb3RA`

[image]

The XML paths are:

- `/feed/entry/title`
- `/feed/entry/yt:videoId`
- `/feed/entry/media:group/media:thumbnail/@url`

I've tried following the [doc and examples](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) but I can extract nothing.

My goal is to print **all** `/entry` in `/feed/`. For example:

```
France paralysed by biggest strike in years - BBC News
6Mm1M-cdKqU
https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/6Mm1M-cdKqU/hqdefault.jpg
```

Comment: What commands have you actually tried?

Comment: `xml sel -t -v "/*" videos.xml`

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate (it's about the namespace) - [XML query by the xmlstarlet](https://superuser.com/a/1780720/332907)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XML query by the xmlstarlet](https://superuser.com/questions/1774726/xml-query-by-the-xmlstarlet)