# XML query by the xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

The Maven settings file looks like:

```xml
<settings
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
    https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>fake31</id>
            <username>username1</username>
            <password>bb</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>fake</id>
            <username>username2</username>
            <password>aa2</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>fake3</id>
            <username>username3</username>
            <password>aa3</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <mirrors>
    [parially cut]
    </mirrors>
</settings>
```

I have to - using xmlstarlet (?) - return a value of the `username` element for the `id = fake`.

I analyzed many examples and did countless tries but I failed.

When I use `/settings/servers/server[id='fake']/username` at https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html, the result is what I expect.

Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The apparently obvious solution won't work, because there is no reference to the `xmlns` namespaces you're using. (Well, technically it will work but it'll not find anything. This used to bite me too.)

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//server[id="fake"]' -v 'username' -n xmlfile
```

Instead you need either to specify the namespaces explicitly with `-N` or use the *default namespace* placeholder, `_`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N mvn="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" -t -m '//mvn:server[mvn:id="fake"]' -v 'mvn:username' -n xmlfile

xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//_:server[_:id="fake"]' -v '_:username' -n xmlfile
```

Mostly I prefer using the default placeholder. Either way, output for your example,

```
username2
```

For others reading this answer I should probably point out that although I've used the much shorter `//server` in my examples, your XPath `//settings/servers/server` is also (almost) correct and provides a tighter target to the relevant element

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//_:settings/_:servers/_:server[_:id="fake"]' -v '_:username' -n xmlfile
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer help me resolve an issue.

Comment: I asked the following [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1786584/xml-query-by-the-xmlstarlet-return-nested-property). Thank you in advance for any further help.